# Troubleshooting Parse Errors when running robot tests on Plone

Tags: plone, robotframework

I'm really not sure what's wrong with my setup. The robot tests were added recently and we've seen them run successfully on another developer's OS X machine.

I'm attempting to run the same robot tests on an Ubuntu machine with Plone and Firefox installed. The package is https://github.com/collective/collective.academicprogrammes

I had to add plone.app.robotframework to the [test] section of my develop.cfg file.
This is what my develop.cfg looks like now:

> [sources]
>
> collective.academicprogrammes = git git@github.com:collective/collective.academicprogrammes.git
>
> [buildout]
>
> test-packages =
>        collective.academicprogrammes[test]
>
> extends =
>       buildout.cfg
>
> extensions +=
>       mr.developer
>
> eggs +=
>
> ```
>   Products.DocFinderTab
>   plone.reload
>   collective.academicprogrammes
> ```
>
> parts +=
>
> ```
>   test
>   diazotools
>   zopeskel
>   robot
> ```
>
> always-checkout = force 
>   sources = sources 
>   auto-checkout = *
>
> [test]
>
> recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
>
> defaults = ['--exit-with-status',
>        '--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
>
> eggs =
>
> ```
>   ${buildout:eggs}
>   ${buildout:test-packages}
> ```
>
> [zopeskel]
>
> recipe = zc.recipe.egg
>
> eggs =
>
> ```
>   ZopeSkel
>   Paste
>   PasteDeploy
>   PasteScript
>   zopeskel.diazotheme
>   zopeskel.dexterity
>   zest.releaser
>   ${buildout:eggs}
> ```
>
> [robot]
>
> recipe = zc.recipe.egg
>
> eggs =
>
> ```
>   Pillow
>   ${test:eggs}
>   plone.app.robotframework
> ```

After running `bin/buildout -c develop.cfg` to install everything I 
attempted to run `bin/test -t robot` I get the following errors:

> File "parser.pxi", line 569, in
>   lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74567)   File "parser.pxi", line 650, in
>   lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75458)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74791)
>
> File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2756, in lxml.etree.fromstring
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54726) bash: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `(' (precise)david@localhost:~/Plone/zeocluster$   File "parser.pxi",
>   line 1571, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82792) bash: syntax error near unexpected token
>   ...   File "parser.pxi",
>   line 1450, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81590) bash:
>   syntax error near unexpected token`('

And it ends with:

> AssertionError: Setup failed: WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t
>   load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpqsX6Ky/webdriver-py-profilecopy
>   Firefox output: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module
>   "canberra-gtk-module"\n*** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG
>   addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes
>   found\n************************************************************\n*
>   Call to xpconnect wrapped JSObject produced this error: 
>   *\n[Exception... "\'[JavaScript Error: "this.updateDisplay is not a function" {file: "chrome://browser/content/search/search.xml" line:
>   83}]\' when calling method:
>   [nsIBrowserSearchInitObserver::onInitComplete]"  nsresult: "0x80570021
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/components/nsSearchService.js :: onSuccess :: line
>   3257"  data:
>   yes]\n************************************************************\n'

Comment: Running the following command 'sudo apt-get install libcanbe
rra-gtk-module' fixes the part of the error about canberra-gtk-module, but I'm still getting the rest of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is two-fold. One has to do with the fact that I installed a lightweight Linux OS that didn't include all the dependencies. Specifically I had to install libcanberra.
To do this on Ubuntu I ran the following command 'sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module'. That was enough to fix the error about canberra-gtk-module.

The second issue was related to the version of Firefox used. It turns out that Selenium 2.34 is not compatible with Firefox 27 (the browser I'm using).
see: 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/py/CHANGES

There are two options, upgrade Selenium to 2.40.0

OR

run robot browser tests against Firefox 25.

I opted to get Firefox 25 and use it when running tests.

Related information about this issue can be found here:

http://seleniumsimplified.com/problems-running-webdriver-on-firefox-26/

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986545